# How can I get a bunch of 1-UPs in New Super Mario Bros(DS)?

Tags: nintendo-ds, new-super-mario-bros

I need to rack up a bunch of free lives in New Super Mario Bros (Nintendo DS).  What is the fastest technique to get a bunch of 1ups / free lives?  (Will the [staircase + koopa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306/where-is-the-infinite-99-lives-staircase-in-the-original-super-mario-bros) trick work in NSMB?  Where's the best staircase for this?)

Comment: It sure will! Don't remember the game offhand to tell you where to go for it, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a while, but I liked playing the first level over and over. It has a Mega Mushroom in it. What you do is let the mushroom out, but don't get it immediately - let it scroll right until it almost falls into a pit. Then pick it up and run like crazy to the right. You'll get a bunch of 1-Ups, including when you smash through the ending flag.

Repeat!